# setError message is affecting scrollview from scrolling android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-scrollview, androiddesignsupport

```
editText.setError(message)
```

- Error layout on EditText is affecting ScrollView from scrolling.

Found one open issue
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=52245

But did not found any solution.

[image]

Comment: did u find any solution of this?

Comment: No i am just changing focus from layout during scrolling.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue aswell. What worked for me was to call `setError()` on the `TextInputLayout` element instead of on `EditText`.

Java:

```
TextInputLayout mEmailInputLayout;
mEmailInputLayout = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.emailInputLayout);
mEmailInputLayout.setError("error Msg");
```

XML:

```
<!--Email-->
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/emailInputLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```